# AJAX Control Toolkit Rounded Corners

Tags: ajaxcontroltoolkit

I was trying to use the AJAX extender Rounded Corners on a normal textbox, but did not work at all. Is this not possible with textboxes?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so. I'd recommend putting your textbox in a div and applying rounded corners to that div.